# Bean introspection in Java

Tags: java, javabeans, introspection

I'm learning for a job interview in Java.
They told me to learn the concepts of Beans introspection, so I searched the web and
read in a couple of sites including the next posts:

- [Java introspection and reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044446/java-introspection-and-reflection)
- [Places where JavaBeans are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-javabeans-are-used)
- [What is a Java Bean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-java-bean-exactly)
- [Java doc - Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)
- [Introspection in Java](http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/CS223/2004F/Handouts/introspection.html)

As far as I understood: Bean is like any other object class in Java, but this class must have the next features:

1. All properties private (use getters/setters)
2. A public no-argument constructor
3. Implements Serializable.

General things:

4. Introspection is giving me the possibility to "examine" an object during run-time, and 
   that way I can get the class properties names, methods names constructors etc.
5. Introspection uses Reflection to get the Information of a class.

**I still have some questions:**

1. Why do I need this kind of a mechanism, meaning, in which cases should I use introspection instead of using any other thing?
2. Is there any difference between bean's introspection and a regular introspection?
3. How it's working besides the methods I can use?

I would be happy if someone could give me his own prospective about this subject, or to give me some kind of a link for useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what they want to know. 
You can use frameworks such as [apache-bean-utils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) to query information about bean structure. 
I developed such a code manually (big mistake! :) ) - 
I used a recursive mechanism based on java bean notation (i.e - setters must begin with "set", 
 
getters begin with "is" for boolean or "get" for all types)
You then can us this code to automate some behavior - 
At my case fo example I wrote a tool that parses WSDL, and creates binding between WS calls
and our application entitites via code. 
The user of our application provided an XML indicating how to perform a mapping - 
i.e - let's say that a WS call returned a Person object, but in our application we had a student entity
so the XML defined how to perform the mapping, and I used code like apache-bean-utils to perform introspection 
and to understand what setters and getters to invoke. 
This was done in contrast to what is done usually in java applications: 
1. Generate Java clients (i.e - use wsdl2java) from WSDL 
2. Compile the application with the client code. 
I can assume introspection can be used in profilers code - for example, 
Since there are many frameworks that use getters and setters , it is very improtant that these methods will be efficient, 
so it's something that mabye profiles should first look into.

Feel free to add more questions