# automatic casting and filling up POJO

Tags: java, reflection

Want to know if there is any way to reuse some of the Java reflection API / SOAP/ web service internal functions or that of an external API to achieve :

1. Have a list of Objects, got from a method over the wire
2. Via config have a list of classes corresponding to these objects
3. A pojo whose properties have to be filled up with 1

Is there a generic + few lines way of doing this?

Example

```
void process(Object pojoToFill, Class[] classesOfSetters, Objects[] values) {
         //what to do here to fill up pojoToFill with values using classesOfSetters, in a generic way?
}

void sample() {
    Object []objects;// filled with values that are needed by Person class, sent over the wire, setters
    Class []propertyClasses = new Class[String.class, Address.class]//from config
    Person person = new Person();
    process(person, propertyClasses, objects);

}


public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Address address;// etc
    // getters and setters

}

class Address {
    private String line1;// other properties and getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Is there some kind of restriction preventing you from using standard masrhalling/unmarshalling techniques such as jaxb?

Comment: No just want to use the standard Java serialization for my app which are run on many servers but all have the same (our code) and run on the same Java version ... its faster and less stack, and we like it. right now have a generic function to send n objects to another jvm , want a generic way to un pack it too (or data driven/ config)

Answer (score 1):

this should be possible by java reflection API.

Pass on the setter method names as well for each of the setter class

```
void process(Object pojoToFill, Class[] classesOfSetters, String[] setterMethods, Objects[] values) {
 for (int i=0; i < classesOfSetters.length; i++){
Method methodToSetValue = classesOfsetter.getMethod(setterMethods[i]);
methodToSetValue.invoke (pojoToFill, Objects[i]);
}        
}
```

As you are working with javabeans (getter/setter methods); you could also use [Bean introspection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342199/bean-introspection-in-java) API.