# How to find all functions with methods for a given class

Tags: r

I'm basically looking for the opposite of `methods(some_function)` , which returns all class-methods that exist for that function.  Is there some easy way to search for all functions which have an explicit `method` for a given object class?
For example, `methods(my_func)` returns a pile of `myfunc.classname` values.  Is there a `functions(my_class)` which would return all functions with a `func.my_class` method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to supply an argument to `class` and nothing to `generic.function` in `methods`. Compare

```
methods(as.matrix) 
[1] as.matrix.data.frame              as.matrix.data.table*             as.matrix.default                
[4] as.matrix.dist*                   as.matrix.noquote                 as.matrix.POSIXlt                
[7] as.matrix.raster*                 as.matrix.SpatialGridDataFrame*   as.matrix.SpatialPixelsDataFrame*
```

With this, which returns methods for the generic class

```
methods(class="matrix")
 [1] anyDuplicated.matrix  as.data.frame.matrix  as.data.table.matrix* as.raster.matrix*     boxplot.matrix        corresp.matrix*      
 [7] determinant.matrix    duplicated.matrix     edit.matrix*          head.matrix           isSymmetric.matrix    lda.matrix*          
[13] qda.matrix*           relist.matrix*        subset.matrix         summary.matrix        tail.matrix           unique.matrix        

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

And this also seems to work for S4 classes as well, e.g.

```
methods(class="data.table")
 [1] $<-.data.table*           [.data.table*             [<-.data.table*           all.equal.data.table*     as.data.frame.data.table*
 [6] as.data.table.data.table* as.list.data.table*       as.matrix.data.table*     dim.data.table*           dimnames.data.table*     
[11] dimnames<-.data.table*    duplicated.data.table*    format.data.table*        head.data.table*          is.na.data.table*        
[16] merge.data.table*         na.omit.data.table*       names<-.data.table*       Ops.data.table*           print.data.table*        
[21] subset.data.table*        tail.data.table*          transform.data.table*     unique.data.table*        within.data.table*
```

Comment: Now this is sad: a year later I completely forgot I'd asked this.  Thank goodness for SO's search tools :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing the concept of introspection and reflection (well-known in Java).

A post about introspection and reflection in Java with links here : [Java introspection and reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044446/java-introspection-and-reflection)

I don't know which technology or language you are using but maybe you will find the equivalent.

Hope this helps ! Bye !